# How to use nth-child selector in tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

i want to select every other element of a some element, for example

```
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

i would like to select the second and fourth div, in css to do that one can do

```
.parent:nth-child(2n) { ... }
```

but in tailwind, i did a bit a research and im still stuck, does anyone know how to do such a selection ?

Comment: *but in tailwind* --> tailwind is CSS and you can write your own CSS. Don't try to find hacky workarounds, write CSS

Answer (score -3):

If you want to select second and fourth elements out of four, you can use `even` pseudo selector. Here is the docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#even